# C++ shared_ptr order of release

Tags: c++, destructor, shared-ptr, lifetime, order-of-execution

In my code, I have

```
void Test(){
   std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A());
   std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::shared_ptr<B>(new B(a->getSomething());
}
```

The problem is, that `a` is released before `b`, but during `b` release I need something from `a`, that was obtained via `a->getSomethig()`. I cannot change `getSomething` method.

Can I change (set) order of releasing shared pointers?

Comment: In the code here, b's destructor is called before a's. I don't see the problem

Comment: Can you share a MVCE then? Basically, share code that has `a` being destroyed before `b` so we can better understand your problem

Comment: Hold a shared pointer to A in B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you reversed the order of objects in the original question (otherwise, the question doesn't make any sense), you do not need to change the order of release, instead, you should use aliasing form of shared_ptr constructor. Something like that:

```
std::shared_ptr<B> b(a, a->getSomething());
```

Comment: I thin that one should use aliasing no matter what: relying on the order of declarations is fragile and goes against the very concept of automatic resource handling by smart pointers.